# Change dialogWidth and dialogHeight's values

Tags: sharepoint-designer, modal-dialog

The calendar web part is too wide and want to change dialogWidth and dialogHeight's values from 500px to 300px. 
Is it possible to change dialogWidth and dialogHeight of a web part like changing the table's width with javascript?

Thank you.

the code about dialogWidth/Height:

```
<div>
javascript:commonShowModalDialog(&#39;{SiteUrl}/_layouts/itemexpiration.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId&#39;,&#39;center:1;
dialogHeight:500px;dialogWidth:500px;
resizable:yes;status:no;location:no;menubar:no;help:no&#39;,function GotoPageAfterClose(pageid){if(pageid == &#39;hold&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/hold.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;);return false;} 
if(pageid == &#39;audit&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/Reporting.aspx?Category=Auditing&amp;backtype=item&amp;
ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;);return false;} if(pageid == &#39;config&#39;) {STSNavigate(unescape(decodeURI(&#39;{SiteUrl}&#39;))+&#39;/_layouts/expirationconfig.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}&#39;); return false;}}, null); return false;
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this is already on technet: [How do I resize a dialog box once it's open?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/d92508be-4b4b-4f78-86d3-5d15a510bb18/)